# Cursor goes out the for contenteditable div box when using placeholder

Tags: html, css

I'm using the contenteditable div to grab user's input.  However,  a big cursor show up when clicked which goes outside the contenteditable div. If removing the rule `:empty:before` the cursor problem seems to be fixed but the placeholder also disappeared.

How to make the cursor back to the normal size but still keeping the placeholder?

```
 <html>
    <div id="comment_box" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Click me to see Omg what a big cursor"></div>

<style>

#comment_box{
    text-align: center;
  background-color: white;

  /*position:relative;*/
  border: 1px solid orange;
  /*height:60px;*/
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  color:black;
  border-radius:5px;
  /*font-size:18px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;

  /*border-color:yellow;*/
}
#comment_box:focus{
  outline-style:solid;
  outline-color:orange;
  outline-width:0px;
}


[contenteditable=true]:empty:before{
  content: attr(placeholder);
  color: #aaa;
  display: block;  For Firefox 
 }

</style>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of cursor are you talking about?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358795(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: can you try removing, display: inline-block from the #comment-box. Does that solve the issue?

Comment: Yeah it solves the issue. Thanks